# ruby request.inspect shows no body

Tags: ruby, http, inspect

I am curious about something.

Why when I do a

```
request.inspect
```

do I get a massive object back that contains no `body`.

However when I do

```
puts request.body
```

I get the value I was looking for.

Can anyone explain this?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect) on the default implementation of `inspect`:

> Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of `obj`. By default, show the class name and the list of the instance variables and their values (by calling `inspect` on each of them). User defined classes should override this method to make better representation of `obj`. When overriding this method, it should return a string whose encoding is compatible with the default external encoding.

If `inspect` is not customized for that `request` object (whatever it is) and `body` is not backed by an instance variable (with a properly computed value at the time of `inspect` call), it is not included in the output.